# Damping iterations

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-linear-algebra

Damping is a way of taming a nonconvergent iteration to get it to converge.  Given a splitting matrix $M$, which gives the iteration $$x^{k+1} = x^{k} + M^{-1}r^{k}$$
where $$r^{k} = b-Ax^{k}$$ 
the corresponding damped iteration with damping factor $\omega < 1$ is defined by
$$x^{k+1} = x^{k} +\omega M^{-1}r^{k}$$
Clearly the splitting matrix of the damped iteration is $\frac{1}{\omega}M$. Show that if $M^{-1}A$ has real, postive eigenvalues, then the damped iteration associated with $M$ converges for sufficiently small $\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

The splitting inducing this iteration is
$$
A=\omega^{-1}M-(\omega^{-1}M-A)
$$
so the iteration converges iff $\rho(T)<1$ where
$$
T:=[\omega^{-1}M]^{-1}(\omega^{-1}M-A)=I-\omega M^{-1}A.
$$
For each (real and positive) eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $M^{-1}A$, the corresponding eigenvalue of $T$ is $1-\omega\lambda$ (and vice versa) so the spectrum of $T$ is real. We need to guarantee hence that $-1<1-\omega\lambda<1$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $M^{-1}A$.

If $\omega\leq 0$, then $\lambda>0$ implies $1-\omega\lambda\geq 1$ and hence $\rho(T)\geq 1$. Therefore, $\omega$ must be positive; hence let $\omega>0$ from now on. The function $\lambda\mapsto 1-\omega\lambda$ is decreasing so to get $\rho(T)<1$ we must guarantee that $-1<1-\omega\lambda_\max$, where $\lambda_\max$ is the largest positive eigenvalue of $M^{-1}A$ (such that $\lambda_\max=\rho(M^{-1}A)$). This gives the condition $\omega<2/\lambda_\max$.